# OpenJPA 1.2.1: fine-grained fetch plan

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

Suppose I have the following:

```
@Entity
class Product {
  @OneToOne(Lazy)
  ProductType type;
}

@Entity
class ProductType {
  @ManyToOne(Lazy)
  ProductFamily pf;
}

@Entity
class ProductFamily {
  String name;
  // ...
}
```

By default, OpenJPA has a fetch depth of **-1**, and it seems that if I query Product:

```
select p from Product p
```

it will end up querying something like this:

```
select p from product p
left join product_type
left join product_family
```

I have read about fetch depth, and I can restrict the fetch depth to **1**, meaning that the query will only fetch immediate relations:

```
select p from product p
left join product_type
```

but how can I customize the query in order to be able to specify a fetch join for **nested relations**? I have tried both `left fetch join` and adding fields to the fetch plan, but it doesn't work.

---

to make it clear: I want **all** `*-to-One relations` to be lazy by default, and then fine-tune the relations via `fetch joins`, but it seems that OpenJPA is ignoring the lazy configuration.

Comment: How are you enhancing your Entities?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand. If you want to be able to specify what must be fetched, you'll need to mark your associations as lazy, and load your objects using queries. By default *ToOne associations are eager, and *ToMany associations are lazy. Once marked as lazy, the following queries are possible:

```
select p from Product p // load only the products

select p from Product p 
left join fetch p.type // load products with their type

select p from Product p 
left join fetch p.type t 
left join fetch t.pf // load products with their type and the family of their type
```

If the association is eager, whatever to code used to load the entity, its association will be fetched.

Comment: What happens is that by default, *-to-One associations are normally fetched because of the max fetch depth. I want to configure all *-to-One to be lazy by default, and then fine tune the fetches. But it seems that when I configure the associations as lazy, OpenJPA will fetch them anyway. The only way I have to avoid this is to set the maxFetchDepth to 1 or so, but this way the join fetches are ignored.

Comment: How do you test if the lazy associations are loaded or not?

Comment: I watch the generated sql queries

Comment: I don't know OpenJPA, but their doc states that the necessary code weaving should be done automatically. You might try to do it at compile-time to make sure: http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.4/apache-openjpa-1.0.4/docs/manual/ref_guide_pc_enhance.html

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I had to turn class transformation in order to enable Lazy Loading. Withouth bytecode enhancement, OpenJPA gives a warning saying just that.